# Azure B2C Custom policies to login with microsoft email

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to create custom policies in Azure B2C by following the process and starters pack mentioned in the link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Now, the issue is that when I access my application URL, it should redirect to microsoft email verification page as my organization will use the microsoft email. Then I will enter a email which if that is valid and the same email is present in Azure B2C tenant as user, then sign-in should be successful and redirect to my appplication. This is not happening now. Currently when I access my application url, it is redirecting to sample UI for sign-in where even after giving the valid email it is throwing error as "We can't seem to find your account." Any suggestions on this please?

It is going to below UI instead of microsoft email verification page:

[UI that is coming from starter pack for sign-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDy6o.png)

The starter Pack I have updated with my tenant details and uploaded and the documentation I created every app registration as suggested.

I need the application to redirect to below microsoft page.

[Expected microsoft page that I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgsiN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you gave is incorrect - it points to StackOverflow!

When you say, "as my organization will use the microsoft email", do you mean an Azure AD account or a Microsoft account? If so, look here to [add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider) an external IDP.

If you mean a B2C account, your problem is probably that you haven't updated the application IDs in the [extension file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-application-ids-to-the-custom-policy) correctly.

**Update**

To remove that page, remove the user journey step that calls "SelfAsserted-Social".

To fix the "sub" issue, ensure you have this line in the RP.

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
```

Comment: Updated the link. My requirement is I have a microsoft email which will be added as an external user to the azure b2c tenant. So what process I need to follow for this?

Comment: Added the expected microsoft redirection I am looking for in the main question.

Comment: You need to pick the correct external IDP from the link I gave you and add it.

Comment: I have tried adding the IDP as per the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy. 

@rbrayb Now the issue is that after authenticating the user successfully, it is redirecting to a page that is asking to provide the Display name, full name, and surname and if those are provided, it is creating a new user in the B2C tenant. How to fix this?

Comment: Error is: error_description=AADB2C: 'B2C_1A_signup_signin' policy in 'b2c.onmicrosoft.com' specifies the subject claim 'sub' which is missing in the claims collection.

Comment: I already have the mentioned line in output claims, Still seeing the "sub" issue. Yes, removing SelfAsserted-Social is directly landing me on the Microsoft page. But the "sub" issue still persists. @rbrayb

Comment: Are you passing objectId? Is it perhaps null?

Comment: ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" line was missing in the technical profile section of the extenstions.xml file. I am getting successfully redirected to the jwt.ms url. But, the issue is that when I try redirecting to my Custom application URL, it is throwing error "Contact your administrator". In the browser Inspect also it is not throwing any error in network

Any way to debug the B2C scenarios?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy